# Only allow to click the submit button, to submit the form

Tags: html, input

I would like to enter the form , 
when press enter the input box , it will submit the form

```
$('input[type=text]').keypress(function(event) {
    if(event.which == 13) {
        //enter pressed
        active($(this));
    }
});
```

Test it on android mobile, but the keypress can not detect the keycode

How to block this behavior? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input:text").keypress(function(event) {

        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
               event.preventDefault();
               active($(this));
        }
});
```

There we use `preventDefault` to block his default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type=text]').keydown(function(event) {

  var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which; 

  if (keyCode == 13) { 
    active($(this));
  } 

});
```